# How to get around a JDBC connection to an Oracle DB from closing (SQLRecoverableException Closed Connection)?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, database-connection

I have written the following code to connect to an Oracle database. This is being used for a REST API. The database I'm connecting to has the IDLE_TIME parameter set to 30 minutes (this can't be changed). If the database connection is idle for over 30 minutes, the following error is thrown: "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Closed Connection". After this error is thrown, the API ceases to work. How do I get around this?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.sql.SQLRecoverableException;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.*;


public class OrcConnector {

    private Queue<Connection> connections;

    private int maxConnections;

    private static final int MAX_CONNECTIONS_DEFAULT = 10;

    public OrcConnector() {

        connections = new LinkedList<Connection>();
        maxConnections = MAX_CONNECTIONS_DEFAULT ;

    }

    public synchronized int getMaxConnections(){
        return maxConnections;
    }

    public synchronized void setMaxConnection (int maxConnections) {
        this.maxConnections = maxConnections;
    }

    public synchronized ConnWrapper getConnection() throws SQLException, BusyConnections {
        Connection availConn;

        System.out.println("I am in OrcConnection");

            if (connections.size() > 0) {
                availConn = connections.poll();
            } else if (connections.size() < maxConnections) {
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                ResourceBundle resource = ResourceBundle.getBundle("database");
                String url = resource.getString("db.url");
                String user = resource.getString("db.user");
                String pass = resource.getString("db.password");
                prop.put("user", user);
                prop.put("password", pass);
                prop.put("autoReconnect", "true");
                prop.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
                prop.put("useUnicode", "true");
                availConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
                System.out.println("I am in OrcConnection");
            } else {
                throw new BusyConnections();
            }
            return new ConnWrapper(availConn, this);
    }

    public synchronized void putConnection(Connection conn) {
        if (conn != null) {
            if (connections.size() < maxConnections) {
                connections.add(conn);
            } else {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println("connection could not be closed" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: My attempt to catch SQLRecoverableException and reestablish the connection did not work.

Comment: Some options: 1. Use a web container to manage the Connections (and connection pool) for you 2. Don't attempt to reuse the connection - only open when necessary, and close when done 3. Not necessarily a recommendation, but an option: use a timer to ping the database at regular intervals to avoid the timeout

Comment: Don't write your own connection pool. Use an existing one. It's not as simple as you seem to think.

Comment: @copeg how would I ping the database at a set interval? I am using Rest Easy for the API

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use UCP (Universal Connection Pool), the connection pool from Oracle which can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html) and then use the [Validate When Borrowing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJUCP/connect.htm#CHDIDJGH) feature. This way you let UCP test the validity of connections when you need one and it will reconnect if needed.